# Looping Through C# Textboxes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have the user input doubles into 4 different textBoxes. Then, once the user clicks the calculate button, the following will happen:

- foreach loop runs, parses textbox.Texts to doubles, and then adds
  them to a list
- for loop runs and indexes through the list, adding
  them all up.
- List item sum from previous step is divided by the number of values in the list result is entered into another textbox.

When I run it, no errors happen, but the result is not displayed in the texbox. Why is nothing getting displayed?

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double gpa = 0;
            List<double> grades = new List<double>();

            foreach(Control textBox in Controls)
            {
                if ((textBox.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Form.Textbox") && (textBox.Name.Contains("gradeBox")))
                {
                    grades.Add(double.Parse(textBox.Text));
                }
            }

            for(int i =0; i<grades.Count; i++)
            {
                gpa += grades[i];
            }
            gpa /= grades.Count;

            gpaBox.Text = gpa.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Did you attach the debugger to your code? Did you try stepping through it line by line to make sure it executes the way you expect?

Comment: Instead of comparing the type name with a string, consider using "pattern matching"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the namespace of textbox is not quite correct. It should be System.Windows.Form**s**.Text**B**ox. Notice "s" and capital "B". Following is the corrected version.

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double gpa = 0;
            List<double> grades = new List<double>();

            foreach (Control textBox in Controls)
            {
                if ((textBox.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox") && (textBox.Name.Contains("gradeBox")))
                {
                    grades.Add(double.Parse(textBox.Text));
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < grades.Count; i++)
            {
                gpa += grades[i];
            }
            gpa /= grades.Count;

            gpaBox.Text = gpa.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, it worked! I can't believe it was something so simple like that.